# how do I configure tortoisehg to work with mutliple repos?

Tags: mercurial, repository, tortoisehg

I've been using tortoisehg to work with a repo using ssh and everything is in order. But now i'm trying to `clone` another repo that uses only `https`, and I'm welcomed with the following error message:

```
URLError: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
[command returned code 255. . .]
```

I tried to localized the settings of my current repo, i.e. remove them from `global settings`, to `...\.hg\hgrc`, but i still get the same error when i try to clone.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: What makes you think that the problem is related to your original repository? It seems to me like you just can't connect to where you are trying to clone from.

Comment: I thought it is using log-in details of the original repo because it doesn't even ask for my passwords.

Comment: No, that's not an authentication error, from the looks of it. Looks more like a firewall.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late response but perhaps its a proxy error...

see: 
[How to clone a codeplex mercurial repository behind a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449133/how-to-clone-a-codeplex-mercurial-repository-behind-a-proxy)

but instead use

```
[https_proxy]
host = proxy name /  ip:port
user = xxxxxxx
passwd = xxxxxxx
```

Comment: 4 years, 9 months ago, I don't think this guy would still be looking for the answer....

Comment: @Timothy - but useful nonetheless :)